# Sum values lower then a threshold with constant

Tags: r

For instance I have a vector:

```
x <- c(6, 22, 18, 5, 19, 14, 17, 88,30, 0, -1, 2, 3)
```

How do I check for values lesser than 17 and change the values to `value + some const`?

something like this:

```
x[x < 17] <- lesser vaue + 18
```

expected output:

```
c(24, 22, 18, 23, 19, 32, 17, 88,30, 18, 17, 20, 21)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

here an example

```
x[x<17] <- x[x<17]+18
```

Answer (score 1):

```
x <- ifelse(x < 17, x + 18, x)
```

Another solution, saying if x is less than 17 add 18 else take x as it is.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is `case_when`

```
library(dplyr)
case_when(x  < 17 ~ x + 18, TRUE ~ x)
#[1] 24 22 18 23 19 32 17 88 30 18 17 20 21
```